# Getting error while integrating eclipse and maven

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

I am new to maven and eclipse configuration. I set up my maven path in eclipse

[image]

Then i made a project run configuration in eclipse

[image]

Here is the snippet of my pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>package</groupId>
<artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>myProject</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
```

Now when i debug my project i get an error that

```
Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for 
package:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT [WARNING] 
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 189, column 15
```

In my pom.xml file i have an entry like this

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Also i am getting error that

```
Failed to execute goal on project myProject: Could not resolve dependencies for 
project pk.training.basitMahmood:myProject:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to 
collect dependencies for [junit:junit:jar:4.4 (test), 
org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.1 (test), 
javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (compile), 
commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5 (compile), 
org.apache.ant:ant-apache-log4j:jar:1.8.0 (compile), 
velocity-tools:velocity-tools:jar:1.4 (compile), 
org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.5 (compile), 
org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:2.5.5 (compile), 
org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.5 (compile), 
org.springframework:spring-test:jar:2.5.5 (compile), 
org.springframework.ws:spring-oxm:jar:1.5.5 (compile), 
org.springframework.ws:spring-oxm-tiger:jar:1.5.6 (compile), 
org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:1.5.6 (compile), 
org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core-tiger:jar:1.5.6 (compile), 
org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security:jar:1.5.6 (compile), 
org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.3 (compile), 
commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8 (compile), 
ant:ant-jakarta-regexp:jar:1.6.1 (compile), 
org.json:json:jar:20090211 (compile),
com.xmlparserv2:LS360_xml_parser:jar:20110919 (compile), 
360_Oracle:toplink:jar:10.1.5 (compile), 
360_MS_SQL:sqlserver:jar:1.0 (compile), 
org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:jar:all:1.5.6 (compile)]:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for velocity-tools:velocity-tools:jar:1.4: 
Could not transfer artifact velocity-tools:velocity-tools:pom:1.4 from/to 
maven2-repository.jboss.com (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2): 
Access denied to 
http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/velocity-tools/velocity-tools/1.4/
velocity-tools-1.4.pom. Error code 403, Forbidden -> [Help 1]
```

However i have all these dependicies in my pom.xml, like

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
.....
</dependencies>
```

Here are the repositories

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.jboss.com</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-apache</id>
        <url>http://ftp.cica.es/mirrors/maven2/</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

Why i am getting these errors? How can i solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important one in that case is that you are missing a version for the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Why have you defined so much repositories and in particular Maven-1 Repository? Just use Central only define other repositories if your really need them.

The best way to test maven builds is to do that on command line if that works perfect put it into Eclipse.

Comment: Hi thanks, actually all those repositories are defined by someone, i need to rectify the code. Any how, after adding version `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 189, column 15` this error has been removed, but i am still getting the jar dependencies error `Failed to execute goal on project myProject:....`. Although all dependencies are defined in pom.xml. can you tell me why i am still getting the error ? Thanks

Comment: actually when i go to command line and run the command `mvn clean install` in the root of my project where pom.xml is present then it works fine, it generates the war file. That's why i am trying to do it in eclipse, so each and every time i didn't go to command line for executing this command.

Comment: The error gone, when making build configuration, i change the Maven Runtime, Can i edit your answer to put a picture of that ?